Issue with target="_top" Links in iframe on iPhone
We are using the Banno digital toolkit plugin bridge to open links from HTML anchor tags with the target="_top" attribute. This works as expected, opening the link inside our app on both desktop and mobile apps.
However, we encountered an issue when the same anchor tag is placed inside an iframe within our content. On Android phones and iPhones, the link opens inside the plugin card face itself rather than in the app. This problem does not occur on the desktop app, where the link opens correctly in the app. I am using iOS Garden App V. 3.12.0 (1277).
As advised, I have created a fork using github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example which is https://github.com/kondekar/dt. I tested it in https mode but I did not include those code changes. I included only change that is relevant (the response). I added a new content file, frame.html, which is placed in the public path. To reproduce the issue, follow these steps:

Render the plugin.
You will see two links: one outside the iframe and one inside the iframe.
The link outside the iframe behaves as designed.
The link inside the iframe opens the content inside the plugin card instead of the app on the mobile platform.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to ensure the link opens in the app on iPhone when inside an iframe?


A few things come to mind that would help narrow things down. Do you really have an iframe embedded within your plugin card's web content?  I'm not sure how Online, Android webview, and iOS webview handle trying to cross the chasm from the iframe up to the parent/normal web content.



You mention 'iPhone' for Banno Mobile - iOS, and compare to Banno Online in the browser. However, what is the experience like on Banno Mobile - Android?



What is the app version and operating system version for Banno Mobile - iOS that you are using?



What is the app version and operating system version for Banno Mobile - Android that you are using?



Either way, it would really be good for you to have a reproducible code example i.e. using https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example or https://github.com/Banno/basic-plugin-example/ as the basis for your example. You could fork one of those repos and provide a link to the changed code that reproduces the problem.


Edited the original question, to include answers to the most questions above.

I have now a reproducible code example in a fork of one of those repos. Details are in the problem description.

I hope others replicated the issue successfully. Any solutions?
